# Get the total sum of 2 multiplied columns SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I have these 3 tables:

**Bill**:

```
idBill
```

**Products**:

```
idProduct
price
```

**BillProducts** (that connects the tables above):

```
idBill
idProduct
quantity
```

Now let's say I wish to get the total price of a certain bill identified by its ID

I would need to multiply the columns of `Products.Price` by `BillProducts.quantity`, get its result and sum all the others products in that `idBill`

Can you guys help me writing that query?

Comment: When you say sum all the other products in that billId do you mean the quantity from the Billsproducts table?

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman Sorry that I wasn't explicit. I want to multiply Products.Price by BillProducts.quantity for each row where idBill matches the id I want, and sum all the result of that multiplication. In other words, when a client purchases products, they get a bill with all the products associated (in BillProducts), and I intent to know the total price of that bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
select sum(p.price * bp.product)
from billproducts bp join
     products p
     on bp.idproduct = p.idproduct
where idbill = <idbill>;
```

You can get this for all bills using `group by`:

```
select idbill, sum(p.price * bp.product)
from billproducts bp join
     products p
     on bp.idproduct = p.idproduct
group by idbill;
```

Notes:

- You do not need to `join` the `bills` table.  All the information you need is in the other two tables.
- You do not need a subquery.
- When you define table aliases, they should be abbreviations for the table names, so the query is easier to follow.

Comment: That's very helpful friend, from those queries you wrote I managed to get the rest of my tasks done :)

Comment: @xickoh . . . This is a much simpler answer to the question that you asked.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTxPRICE) AS SUMED, IDBILL FROM (
SELECT (A.QUANTITY * B.PRICE) AS QUANTxPRICE,a.IDBILL
FROM BILLPRODUCTS AS A
JOIN PRODUCTS AS B ON 
A.IDPRODUCT = B.IDPRODUCT
JOIN BILL AS C
ON A.IDBILL = C.IDBILL
) AS X
GROUP BY IDBILL
```

[image]

Comment: That is very appreciated mate, is there any way to get the results in a single query (without creating temporary tables?) If so, I'd be very glad

Comment: Sorry please see edit i think that will work for you temps only for example purpose.

Comment: Thank you, hope you're aware you've helped me doing a class :)

Comment: @xickoh, if you want to use stackoverflow to cheat in your schoolwork, that's your problem and your responsibility. We are not the school police. If you bring a good question to the site (one that is well expressed and will be useful to future users), people will answer it. But you _will_ get busted at school, now or later.

Comment: @alexis no cheating at all mate, just helped me solving this issue :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, I guess I misinterpreted what you wrote, sorry. All the more reason _not_ to try to be the school police...